# Resetting an array length in v8/C++

Tags: c++, v8

Using the latest v8 api from google, in C++, how can I remove the elements of an existing array and change its length?  Where `arr` is a `v8::Handle<v8::Array>`, and `n` is an index (less than the length of the array), I am finding that `arr->Delete(n)` doesn't seem to change the length of the array as I would have expected.